# Get base url from a scheduled task in application start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, base-url, application-start

I have a `TaskScheduler` with the function `EmailInactiveUsers` that I start from `Application_Start()`.

I need a link to the root of my application in my email that I send out. But how do I get the ***base url*** of my application without having access to an `HttpContext`?

My backup solution would be to add this url to the `web.config`, but it would be nice if I could do this dynamically since we are deploying this application to a lot of different places.

*Application_Start*

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...

    TaskScheduler.EmailInactiveUsers();
}
```

*TaskScheduler*

```
public class TaskScheduler
{
    ...

    public static void EmailInactiveUsers()
    {
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<InactiveUsersCheck>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

*InactiveUsersCheck*

```
public class InactiveUsersCheck : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        ...

        // Get base url here but there's no Request or HttpContext.Current available
        var Url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, I am having the exact same issue?

Comment: Good question, I'm afraid I'm not involved in this project anymore. If I get the possibility to look at it again I'll share the solution or the workaround.